# javascript prompt return type is object always?

Tags: javascript

```js
function check_color(){
 
 color_input = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors: \n\n"+
        "blue, cyan, gold, gray, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow \n\n"+
        "What color am I thinking of?");
 
 if(color_input != null || color_input != undefined){
 
  if(typeof (color_input) != 'string') {
   alert("This is not any color. \n\n"+
     "Please enter color in text format");
   return false;
 }
 
  if(colors.indexOf(color_input) < 0){
   alert("Sorry, i don't recognize your color. \n\n"+
     "Please try again");
   return false;
 }
  }
  else{
   alert("Please enter some input");
   return false;
  }
}
```

Why always the first-if block is being executed when trying to run this code ? Can someone expalin please ?

Comment: This is how OR condition works. `color_input != null || color_input != undefined` should be `color_input != null && color_input != undefined`

Comment: @Tushar Isn't it and condition ? Corect me if i'm wrong.

Comment: && = and, || = or

Comment: What browser returns undefined for prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the problem but in jsFiddle this code snippet works as expected:

```
function check_color() {
   color_input = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors: \n\n" +
         "blue, cyan, gold, gray, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow \n\n" +
         "What color am I thinking of?");

   colors = ["blue", "cyan", "gold", "gray", "magenta", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"];

  if (color_input != null) {

     if (typeof(color_input) != 'string') {
        console.log("This is not any color. \n\n" +
           "Please enter color in text format");
        return false;
     }

     if (colors.indexOf(color_input) < 0) {
        console.log("Sorry, i don't recognize your color. \n\n" +
           "Please try again");
        return false;
     }

     console.log("your color:" + color_input);
  } else {
     console.log("Please enter some input");
     return false;
  }
}
check_color();
```

I had to add the colors array to the snippet (I'm assuming you had it elsewhere). I also took out the "|| undefined" because prompt only returns a string or null.

Because of that, you can simplify the code as such:

```
function check_color() {
   color_input = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors: \n\n" +
      "blue, cyan, gold, gray, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow \n\n" +
      "What color am I thinking of?");

   colors = ["blue", "cyan", "gold", "gray", "magenta", "orange", "red",     "white", "yellow"];

   if (color_input) { // null would be false
      if (colors.indexOf(color_input) < 0) {
         console.log("Sorry, i don't recognize your color. \n\n" +
            "Please try again");
         return false;
      }

      console.log("your color:" + color_input);
   } else {
      console.log("Please enter some input");
      return false;
   }
}
check_color();
```

Comment: Thanks for the much more info. prompt only returns a string or null, so no need to check if the color_input is string type when it is not null.

Answer (score 1):

where is the "colors" 
if(colors.indexOf(color_input)

i am getting console error here.
please add a colors array